# regex - match brackets but exclude them from results

Tags: regex

I have this example string

```
[can be anything here %+^-_][can be anything here %+^-_][can be anything here %+^-_][can be anything here %+^-_][can be anything here %+^-_][can be anything here %+^-_][can be anything here %+^-_][can be anything here %+^-_]
```

My pattern is `(\[[^\]]+\])`

An I get this as a result

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [1] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [2] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [3] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [4] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [5] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [6] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [7] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [1] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [2] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [3] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [4] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [5] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [6] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
            [7] => [can be anything here %+^-_]
        )

)
```

## Problem 1

Why result has two array? Anyway it's not a big deal but I wonder.

## Problem 2

How can I get rid of brackets at the beginning and at the end of each array value, using only regex. Like this.

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [0] => can be anything here %+^-_
                [1] => can be anything here %+^-_
                [2] => can be anything here %+^-_
                [3] => can be anything here %+^-_
                [4] => can be anything here %+^-_
                [5] => can be anything here %+^-_
                [6] => can be anything here %+^-_
                [7] => can be anything here %+^-_
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does the result have two arrays?**

Because putting something in parenthesis (`()`) assigns it a group number, that's what group 1 is. Group 0 is your entire match. See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for more info.

**How can I get rid of brackets at the beginning and at the end of each array value?**

Change your regex to:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

For the above, the matching `[]` are outside of the `()`. This will make group 1 what you want.

**To make group 0 what you want, with no group 1**, you'll have to use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\])
```

But this is largely unnecessary.

`(?<=\[)` is positive look-behind, checking that the previous character is a `[`, but doesn't include it in the match.
`(?=\])` is positive look-ahead, checking that the next character is a `]`, but doesn't include it in the match.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the braces out of your capturing group:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

You have two arrays because one is the full match of your regex and the other what has been captured by the `()`.