# How to pattern match [ and ] in Java?

Tags: java, regex

The string is something in the format:

```
[anything anything]
```

with a space separating the two, 'anything's.

I've tried:

```
(string).replaceAll("(^[)|(]$)","");

(string).replaceAll("(^\[)|(\]$)","");
```

but the latter gives me a compilation error and the first doesn't do anything. I implemented my current solution based on:

[Java Regex to remove start/end single quotes but leave inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315053/java-regex-to-remove-start-end-single-quotes-but-leave-inside-quotes)

Looking around SO yields me many questions that answer problems similar to mine but implementing their solutions do not work (they either do nothing, or yield compilation errors):

[regex - match brackets but exclude them from results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742714/regex-match-brackets-but-exclude-them-from-results)

[Regular Expressions on Punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705112/regular-expressions-on-punctuation)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the \ must be escaped

Comment: Somebody posted the correct solution, and deleted it as I was commenting on it. Whoever it was, it was correct, so please re-post!

Comment: @mescalinum why must the \ be escaped? I thought that \ itself was an escaping character, so that when you do \\[, it would escape the [? If I do \\\[, wouldn't it actually be matching \\[?

Comment: You have to escape the \ as \\ in a Java literal string, so that the regex parser then interprets it as \\[ (which means a literal [ )

Comment: Wow, okay yea that actually makes sense. Is this language dependent? I believe SO's regex guide doesn't do this, which was confusing me. @aryn.galadar

Comment: @ylun.ca I also saw that correct solution. I guess suggestion was to use double '\\' instead of single '\' in your current regex.

Comment: Yes, double-escape is a Java thing - the regular expression itself should just be a single \, but Java treats the \ character as an escape character as well, so you have to double it.

Comment: Thank you, would you like to post an answer? Since the other person seemingly decided to change their mind about answering @aryn.galadar.

Comment: @apgp88 Yes that suggestion worked in my script. And the reason was as aryn stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both Java and regex treats the \ character as an escape character, you actually have to double them when using in a Java literal string.
So the regular expression:

```
(^\[)|(\]$)
```

in a Java string actually should be:

```
"(^\\[)|(\\]$)"
```